# Angular login form response error

Tags: typescript, angular5

Hi everyone I have the below error, is not a error but my mind has blew up with this, I don't understand why.

---

To put you in situation I make a petition to the server through a service

```
public loginuser(username : String , password :  String){
      const body = {
          username : username,
          password : password,
      }

      var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({'No-Auth':'True' });
      return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/access/login', body ,{ headers: reqHeader });
}
```

and in the component I have the below code:

```
  OnSubmit(form: NgForm){

       this.userService.loginuser(this.username,this.password).subscribe(
           (data : any)=>{
               console.log(data);
               localStorage.setItem('userToken',data.token);
               this.router.navigate(['/login']);
           },
           (err : HttpErrorResponse)=>{
               console.log(err.error);
           }
       );
   }
```

okay, until here is everything okay, we submit the form, call the on submit function, call the service and we send the data to my api. This part works.

---

Now that we have the code to send the data to the server we can obtain two possible responses:

**first:**

```
http code : 201
{token : "the token"}
```

in the above situation my code works as expected

---

**second**

```
http code : 404
{
    "status_code":31,
    "status_message":"Username or password invalid"
}
```

---

Now comes the weird thing about every this, when the username/password is valid I receive the token, I save it and I can give access to my application, but when the **username/password is wrong** I receive two responses one with a error, and another one with the second response. So the application is saying me: **man, u have made a bad request but at the same time a good request because look, this response is okay, is the response that we expected from the server.**

---

To show this to you better I am going to ilustrate this with an image:

[image: weird real situation]

with the image you can see the problem, but at the same time I am catching the error in the componen so is not a functionality problem, but is annoying. If someone goes to the console, and see that "error" is like.... really?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you make a browser console application?

Comment: The problem is that I dont want to have dirty the console with that kind of “errors” and in the other hand I don’t want to show to the people who is going to use my web application the url to the api. I want it 100% transparent for the user

Comment: but this is not what you decide. The browser decides what to show and what not to show in the console. Your server sends 404, the browser prints it because normally [404 is an error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and you cannot do anything with that, regardless of your personal preferences. You have two options: change the status code to 2** or live with the console *error*. And, actually, status code 404 is very much not matching the `invalid user or password` error message.

Comment: In fact, what you are fighting against is absolutely normal. Nobody cares of errors in console unless they interfere the user experience, because they are, wait for it, invisible to 99.999% of the users

Comment: Okay  so I don’t have more options so I won’t fight anymore arround it and I will focus in another parts of the web. But I don’t like the idea to show muy api in the console.

Comment: LOL your api is shown in the network section of the browser console and it is way more than any of your 404s

Comment: :( I am new on this and I don’t know if is good to show my api to the public :/ unless three routes in the rest u need an authorization but I don’t know. Is bad to show this in the console?

Comment: As long as the user browser is an external client you cannot make it different. Your API is public, because otherwise the browser cannot access it, so the only and the best you can do is protecting the API by e.g authentication / authorization. You should accept the fact that everybody will be able to see your api

Comment: Okay thanks for take your time telling me all of this. So u are saying time that I could see the api for example from Netflix, although I wouldn’t have permissions about it.

Comment: Yes. You can see everything what your browser is able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just receive 1 response (with status code 404 along with your custom object) when the username/password is wrong. And as intent, browsers will log to console all 4xx and 5xx errors (but you still receive your custom object). The only thing you can do to stop that error from showing is change status code of #2 possibility to non-error code like 200 or 201.

Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: I thought to do that for example: put the the 201 code in all the situations, and put a header called : secondary_error with the 404 so I make an interceptor and in each response I look for the secondary_error and if is 401 or 404 make some actio. But doing this I would be modifying my api not being rest more time , and I don’t like that. I want the 404 error but without dirty the console and making it transparent for the user. Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry it is not possible, internet browsers is the one who print the errors to console. But in my opinion that error is fine, normal user will not open console and see if any errors are there, don't you think?